# Free a tree structure with a non recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, tree, recursive-datastructures

Suppose I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct tree_suspects {
    char **description;
    struct tree_suspects *right_description;
    struct tree_suspects *wrong_description;
}
```

.. and I want to `free`every node after allocating every one of them with `malloc`.

The tree should be capable of holding hundreds of nodes without a problem. So using recursive functions would be greatly inefficient to stack frames, so is there any form of loop or something that would allow me to group all nodes in an array ? Is recursion really the only way to do it ?

Comment: Can you change your nodes to contain a pointer to the parent? Otherwise, you always need O(height) memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can use any list, stack or queue structure, but that would not provide significant advantages unless you know the total number of elements (in that case, you can pre-allocate the list and use it similar to a ring buffer).

Are you sure that recursion is a problem anyway? A few 100 nodes sounds completely fine to me with the usual recursion. What architecture are you on?

If you're worried about memory accesses, you should simply make sure to put those nodes and their data in a similar memory location. Since you're using a binary tree, you can at least put the tree itself in an array (this has an overhead of at most n-1, given n nodes in the tree). I think optimizing the strings is not required, but if you want to do that, too, then use e.g. subindexed char arrays.

Regarding the storage layout for the tree structure, balanced trees are very easy to store (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). Unbalanced trees should be avoided in that case, I suggest something like red black trees, which are not too difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

> using recursive functions would be greatly inefficient to stack

Hundreds of nodes in a balanced tree is not a big deal: a balanced tree with a dozen of levels will easily fit more than a thousand, so recursion would not a problem in this case.

If the tree is unbalanced, you could build a non-recursive function to process it by keeping an explicit stack of nodes to be freed. Push the root onto the stack, and make a loop that takes the next element off the stack, pushes its two children onto the stack, and then frees the node itself. This algorithm would traverse the entire tree, and stop when the stack is empty.